# Refused to load the font because it violates the following Content Security Policy

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars

Есть проект на express, где просто выводились html-файлы через sendFile. Проект начал расширяться, потребовался шаблонизатор. Выбрал Handlebars. Изначально думал, что у меня в проекте какой-то косяк. Но в итоге, пройдя несколько "пошаговых инструкций" наткнулся на ту же самую проблему. [Вот пример гайда](https://medium.com/@waelyasmina/a-guide-into-using-handlebars-with-your-express-js-application-22b944443b65), который я полностью воспроизвёл. Прям до запятой и точки. В итоге всё равно получил ошибку:

Refused to load the font 'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v14/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_epG3gfD_vx3rCubqg.woff2' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

И так со всеми шрифтами. Но я не понимаю, ведь никаких шрифтов я не использовал. Там голый html даже без особых стилей.

В своём проекте появлялась точно такая же проблема, НО, шаблон без переменных - отображался, как только я хотел "протянуть" навигацию по всему сайту через {{> menu }} появлялась ошибка.

Comment: Так и не понял в чём была проблема, но сделал всё через официальный гайд и ошибки нет. Всё работает, полёт нормальный. Почему ошибка появлялась - так и не понял. Вот [ссылка](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars) на официальный туториал.

Comment: А с [github](https://github.com/WaelYasmina/handlebars-guide) собирать пробовал?

Comment: И да, вполне возможно это какое-то расширение в браузере чудит) uBlock умеет лочить внешние скрипты, например.

Comment: присоединяюсь к предположению @vp_arth про браузерное расширение. отключите все расширения и, если ошибки не будет, включайте по одному + перезагрузка страницы, пока ошибка не повторится